# Error generating signed APK on Android Studio 'Access is allowed from event dispatch thread only.'

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, signing

The full error message is:

```
Throwable
Access is allowed from event dispatch thread only.
Details: Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 5,4,main] 1188159197
Our dispatch thread:Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 0.9.2#AI-135.1569493, eap:false,6,main] 2038027461
SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 0.9.2#AI-135.1569493, eap:false,6,main] 2038027461
```

Does anyone know some way to resolve this or some workaround to still create a signed APK? My Android studio version is 0.9.2